# c# reflectin: calling method with generic type and generic parameter for given instance of class

Tags: c#, reflection

I need to call generic method with generic parameter using reflection, where generic type is supplied as parameter within string. There are some examples online for generics and reflection, but I still cannot get this to work.

Without reflection:

```
        string typeName = "EventType"; // as param1 -> type name
        string content = ""; //as param2 -> some json cotnent

        IMyBus bus = new MyBus();
        switch (typeName)
        {
            case "EventType":
                IEventType content = Deserialize<IEventType>(content);
                bus.Publish<IEventType>(content);
                break;
            case "EventType2":
                IEventType2 content2 = Deserialize<IEventType2>(content);
                bus.Publish<IEventType2>(content2);
                break;
        }
```

Instead I would like to rewrite it using reflection to supply more EventTypes without rewriting this particular code.

Below are my test classes:

```
 public interface IMyBus **//TWO METHODS HERE, WE NEED TO CALL FIRST ONE!**
 {
     void Publish<T>(T message, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken)) where T : class; //THIS SHOULD BE CALLED
     void Publish<T>(T message, int i, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken)) where T : class;
  }

  // Interface implementation
  public class MyBus : IMyBus
  {
      public void Publish<T>(T message, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken)) where T : class
      {  ... }
      public void Publish<T>(T message, int i, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken)) where T : class
      {  ... }
    }

    public interface IEventType { int forTest { get; set; } }

    public class EventType : IEventType { public int forTest { get; set; } }

    public interface IEventType2 { int forTest2 { get; set; } }

    public class EventType2 : IEventType2 { public int forTest2 { get; set; } }
```

And here is what I already tried:

```
 IMyBus bus = new MyBus();
 EventType content = new EventType() { forTest = 1 };
 var eventTypeName = $"ConsoleApp.EventType";
 var iEventTypeName = $"ConsoleApp.IEventType";

 Type intEvType = Type.GetType(iEventTypeName);
 Type evType = Type.GetType(eventTypeName);

 MethodInfo openGenericMethod = typeof(IMyBus).GetMethod("Publish", 2, new Type[] { intEvType, typeof(CancellationToken) });
 MethodInfo closedGenericMethod = openGenericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(evType);
 object o2 = closedGenericMethod.Invoke(bus, new object[] { content });
```

But this is wrong. `openGenericMethod`  is always null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for this situation better to find method manually based on name and number of parameters:

```cs
 MethodInfo openGenericMethod = typeof(IMyBus).GetMethods()
                                .SingleOrDefault(m => m.Name == "Publish" 
                                                && m.IsGenericMethod 
                                                && m.GetParameters().Count() == 2);
```

But you are going to call method with `optional` parameters. That's why you should use other `Invoke`  method where you can define binding flag:

```cs
MethodInfo closedGenericMethod = openGenericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(evType);

closedGenericMethod.Invoke(bus, BindingFlags.OptionalParamBinding, null, 
new object[] { content, Type.Missing }, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I've tested it in the test ConsoleApp. It works.

Comment: And what if I actually have also third Publish method that also has two parameters:
Task Publish<T>(object values, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken)) where T : class;  ? (in my example it was IMyBus, but in reality I have IPublishEndpoint from MassTransit assembly)

Comment: You can check first paramater type

Comment: `m.GetParameters().First().ParameterType == typeof(object)`

Comment: @renathy Did it help you or I should think about better implementation of my idea?